# Decimal value 1,5 ends up as 15 in DB - how, why?

Tags: c#, ado.net, decimal

Greetings good people of the internet:)

I have a string value "1,5" which after Convert.ToDecimal() ends up as 1.5M when looking at it in debugger. So far so good I guess. The decimal value then gets passed to a stored procedure call inside a dataset. The type of parameter I am interested in is defined as NUMBER (7,2) in DB so it should allow for numbers that have digits after decimal separator.

The problem is that somewhere along the line the decimal value looses its separator and joins the precision with scale making up completely new number as indicated in the title of this post. I even tried setting Precision and Scale inside parameters' collection in that stored procedure call to match with DB (7,2), but it it did not help either.

Do you have any idea what may be happening here?

EDIT:

Here is the code that calls the stored proc:

`CaseFactory.UtilsAdapter.SetCaseAction(DefId, action, doneBy, assignedTo, comment, status,
                    searchStatus, priority, access, relStatus, relStatusFixKit, totalhrs,
                    out Common.RETURN_CODE, out Common.RETURN_TEXT);`

=> SetCaseAction is just calling stored proc in DB using DataSet mechanics.
'totalhrs' is the param I am interested in is a decimal 1.5M at this point. I have also checked NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS in Oracle and they are set to ', '

So it uses comma for decimals and space for thousands. Nothing unusual I can see there. Only strange thing may be that '1,5' ends up as '1.5M' with a dot inside after ToDecimal(), which may be interpreted incorrectly. It seems unlikely however, because the regional settings on my server use ',' as decimal separator as well, unless .NET uses some different settings? Really confused.

Comment: "The decimal value then gets passed to a stored procedure call inside a dataset." -> I am not sure this part is clear enough. Can you share some code to make this part clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you are converting it at some point without the correct culture, for example concatenating it (instead of using a parameter) into a TSQL query via `ToString()`, or simply using the wrong culture when calling `ToDecimal`. "1,5" is ambiguous between "1 decimal point 5" and "1 group separator 5"; the latter case is parsed as 15.

Comment: The OP said that when he's debugging, the converted value shows up as `1.5M` correctly, so I'm going for the `ToString()` issue.

Comment: Not sure which culture it was using, but surely NOT the one I had set up on that system in regional settings. Anyway, I started trying out different cultures frantically and specifying Finnish culture when calling ToDecimal() did it for me, so I will have to accept this answer although it is still not clear to me which culture was used originally. Thanks

Comment: @dream3n to repeat, though; the fact that culture *mattered* tells me that you are writing your query wrong. You should be using parameters. They don't suffer localization issues (and are safer from attack, and allow plan re-use)

Comment: @Marc I am not sure I get your point; Ado.net stored procedures USE parameters under the bonnet.

Comment: @dream3n yes... but for this error to happen, *somewhere* you are treating this as a string rather than a decimal / etc

Comment: Ah, that is right, but only because I am getting it as a string. I have no influence over the typing of this parameter when it arrives. I get your point though and it should be best practice to use decimal from the start. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I'd imagine it's a localisation problem - commas are used to separate thousands, rather than to indicate decimal places in a lot of systems. Check out the language setting on your database.

Comment: A side note: if the value is being passed to the DB as a *parameter*, culture shouldn't matter. But I agree with the overall diagnosis.

Answer (score 1):

The decimal separator in SQL is `.`, not `,`. So **1,5** is interpreted as **15**, not **1.5**. To avoid this kind of issue, always use parameterized queries rather than encoding the values directly into the query text.

Answer (score 1):

Some code on how you pass the value to the stored procedure would be usedful (if you're doing it yourself).

Some people still use `String.Format` to generate query strings. Apart from causing errors like the one you're describing, this is open to SQL-injections.

You should use parameterized queries. Usually, doing something like this will work:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("...", connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myDecimal", decimalVariable);
```

**EDIT**
Of course, this should not be done for just *some* of the parameters, but for *all* parameters for the stored procedure! The above is just a sample on how to pass parameters to the stored procedure in the first place.

Comment: Agreed - but if it *does* turn out to be the case, I worry for the other non-parameter values. Concatenation is not good (except in controlled scenarios). (this is a note for the OP, not a critique of this answer)

Comment: Of course, this is just an example on how to parameterize a query at all. Of course, `AddWithValue` should be called for *all* parameters!

Answer (score -1):

As Thomas said, in SQL the decimal separator in SQL is a "."

In this case you could just use:

yourVariable.Replace(',','.')

And then, pass the parameter to the function that does the transaction.

Comment: Right. What about computers in the English realm? Where 1,300.5 is a valid decimal number? Then you'd end up with 1.300.5 - what's that supposed to be? So much for culture-aware software development :)

Comment: Right, that solution works in this strict case ("1,5"), and similar.